# Can I apply for a Schengen visa using Student Status letter, without indicating purpose and duration of travel?

Tags: visas, switzerland, multiple-entry, applications, uk-residents

For residents of UK, the [documents for Swiss visiting visa application](https://www.vfsglobal.ch/switzerland/uk/pdf/Visit-visa_EN_050215.pdf) include one such item:

> (for student) student letter confirming the purpose and duration of the trip to Switzerland and the date of returning to work or school

However, I go to Switzerland just to visit my relatives. Therefore, my school is not able to confirm the purpose and duration of my travel, since I am not travelling on behalf of my school.

In this case, can I provide only a Status Letter proving I am a student of my university, without indicating travelling purpose and duration on that very letter?

In addition, I am trying to apply for two-year multiple entry Schengen visa.

Answer (score 2):

I sent an enquiry to visaswiss.uk@vfshelpline.com. Got an answer the next day:

> Thank you for your email.   Kindly be advised the ‘letter of status’
>   is accepted by The Embassy of Switzerland. Please note the letter must
>   be dated not older than a month and should have a pen signature
>   Please do not hesitate to contact us for any further information or
>   clarification you might need.   Best regards,

In conclusion, providing only the status letter is OK.